# Facebook developer tool throw: Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, curl, thumbnails

I am the admin of wordpress blog and i cannot publish the posts in Facebook with thumbnails.
This problem only appear with the posts, so I can link homepage and static pages.
When I use the Facebook Open Graph Debugger in homepage or static pages i get correct data and Facebook can read all og tags, but when i use it with any post I get that:

"Could not retrieve data from URL"
"Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received"

Here are examples:

Correct: http://www.diversionerotica.com/

Wrong: http://www.diversionerotica.com/dia-del-padre-regala-una-sesion-de-fotos-erotica/

Any ideas?

Thanks.

- EDIT -

Here are more information:

1- The wordpress is on a ISS7.

2- The SEO plugin is Yoast Worpress SEO v1.5.2.2

3- og: tags inside HEAD tag generated by plugin:

```
    <!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.5.2.2 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="Regalo muy especial, con el que lo pasaréis en grande y os aseguro que la diversión erótica crecerá por momentos: SESIÓN DE FOTOGRAFÍA ERÓTICA."/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.diversionerotica.com/dia-del-padre-regala-una-sesion-de-fotos-erotica/" />
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+DiversioneroticaCom" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Día del padre: Regala una sesión de fotografía erótica - diversionerotica.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Regalo muy especial, con el que lo pasaréis en grande y os aseguro que la diversión erótica crecerá por momentos: SESIÓN DE FOTOGRAFÍA ERÓTICA." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.diversionerotica.com/dia-del-padre-regala-una-sesion-de-fotos-erotica/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="diversionerotica.com" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="dia del padre" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="fotografía" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="regalo" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Juguetes" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Ropa Sexy" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Sin categoría" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-03-15T12:46:32+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2014-03-15T13:09:38+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2014-03-15T13:09:38+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.diversionerotica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sesion_fotografia_erotica.jpg" />
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

Sorry if it's few information, but i cannot debug any post. Every error or warning in homepage was solved.
I have tried to make all changes I found searching in google and stackoverflow but the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: Well that info is a bit vague, post some code and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this problem wasn't related with Open Graph Tags. I was very confused because there were not enough information from Facebook about that.
I thought that there was a problem in my code and Facebook debugger couldn't read the Open Graph Tags, but the problem was really that my server spent a lot of time to response the requests, and then Facebook Debugger threw a Timeout.

I was so confused because the response of homepage and static pages were correct, and the problem happened only with posts pages.

This problem was solved using a plugin for caching post pages. In this case I am using "WP Super Cache" plugin. Now the response of post pages is about 2 second, and Facebook Debugger can analyse Open Graph Tags correctly.