# Facebook OG tags not working automatically

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are facing an issue with Facebook shares. Basically whenever we post a new article, Facebook debugger can't see the og tags (though all tags are there) and we have to manually scrape the links again 10x times to get the preview working.

Here are the og tags we include in our posts:

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:title" content="Σαν σήμερα - Famagusta News" /><meta property="og:description" content="Διαβάστε τα σημαντικότερα γεγονότα της ημέρας στο Famagusta.News" /><meta property="og:url" content="https://famagusta.news/san-simera/199499/" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="Famagusta News" /><meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/famagusta.news" /><meta property="article:section" content="Σαν Σημερα" /><meta property="article:published_time" content="2019-03-12T22:06:39+00:00" /><meta property="fb:app_id" content="447915658939075" /><meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.famagusta.news/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/12/snsmr5-1200x630.jpg" /><meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdn.famagusta.news/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/12/snsmr5-1200x630.jpg" /><meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" /><meta property="og:image:height" content="630" /><meta property="og:image:alt" content="Σαν σήμερα" />
```

And here is the error we receive on 1st attempt:

> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Missing
>   Properties The following required properties are missing: og:url,
>   og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id Curl Timeout
>   The request to scrape the URL timed out. Curl Error Curl error: 28
>   (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)

Preview the results [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffamagusta.news%2Fsan-simera%2F199499%2F)

Our website is using an SSL certificate, Cloudflare (basic) and KeyCDN for the images.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://` URL into `og:image` and `https://` URL into `og:image:secured` or into another `og:image`

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

According to the docs, you have to add `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` to make sure it gets loaded immediately.

Edit: I just saw that you did provide the tags. It seems that there is a problem with your server, that error is discussed here: [Facebook developer tool throw: Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461368/facebook-developer-tool-throw-curl-error-operation-timeouted-operation-timed)

Comment: Hello, we include both tags:
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />

Comment: I've seen the discussion. I'm also using a caching system (WP Rocket) but that does not solve my problem.